# Sources for infrastructure damage due to heavy rains in Peru?

Tags: peru, natural-disasters

The recent heavy rains in Peru, according to e.g. [this 28 March article from The Weather Network](https://www.theweathernetwork.com/us/news/articles/the-wider-image-peru-after-the-floods/80815) have resulted in a lot of infrastructure damage.

> According to official data, the flooding has damaged some 4,660 miles of roads and 509 pedestrian and vehicular bridges.
>   Portions of the Pan-American Highway North, which unites the entire coastal strip of Peru, have fallen victim to the unrelenting rains and overflowing rivers.
>   ...
>   Transport Minister Martin Vizcarra said that of the 509 damaged bridges, more than 100 have completely collapsed.

I'm travelling to (through) Peru from mid-May to mid-June<sup>*</sup>, and I don't expect the infrastructure to recover very quickly:

*With the first quarter of 2017 not even over, the El Niño weather effects on Peru are already totaling $3.1 billion in damages* ([source](http://www.as-coa.org/articles/peru-update-economic-and-political-costs-mother-nature-and-poor-planning))

Are there sources (in Spanish, if necessary) where up-to-date information about the infrastructure (roads, railways, airports) is available?

<sup>* From Lima southward along the coast, then lake Titicaca, Macchu Picchu, then east into the jungle. Most damage seems to be in the northern parts of the country, but Lima also has damage, like the collapse of the Solidarity Bridge.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a pdf [map with current access constraints](http://www.logcluster.org/sites/default/files/maps/per_op_accessconstraints_a3p_20170330.pdf) as of 30 March 2017, provided by the logistics cluster of the World Food Program. 
[A look into their archives](http://www.logcluster.org/search?search_api_views_fulltext=peru&search=Search) shows a previous version as of 28 March, so they seem to be regularly updated while need is.
One item on the map says:

> Viru Bridge
>   Ruptura del puente por el Rio Viru.
>   Reparación estimada de dos semanas
>   29/03/2017

which means you should no longer be affected if things go somewhat by plan.

Reliefweb also links a [map with the flooding situation in Lima](http://reliefweb.int/map/peru/lima-peru-flood-situation-24032017-delineation-map) and [Sullana](http://reliefweb.int/map/peru/sullana-peru-flood-situation-25032017-grading-map) provided by the European commission. You can find more information by just searching the site.

Obviously your travel is far ahead so you will want to check back in a while. Also the maps show acute constraints but not necessarily how quickly infrastructure will be restored. For this it will be best practice to inquire with local sources (tour orga, hotels, tourism bureaus) a few weeks prior. Probably also itineraries on Google maps will be updated about the new situation by then.

---

[Added by OP (5 Apr 2017)] [Peru: Heavy Rains and Floods Summary - UN Resident Coordinator Situation Report No. 05 (As of 5 April 2017)](http://reliefweb.int/report/peru/peru-heavy-rains-and-floods-summary-un-resident-coordinator-situation-report-no-05-5)

---

[Added by OP (18 Apr 2017) to keep all information in one place] There is [an ongoing thread at the LonelyPlanet forum](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/americas-south-america/peru/safety-check-activated-for-the-whole-of-peru-flooding?page=1) about this